# solr spatial bad performance

Tags: java, performance, solr, lucene

I'm using SOLR-3.4, spatial filtering with the schema having LatLonType (subType=tdouble). I have an index of about 20M places. My basic problem is that if I do bbox filter with cache=true, the performance is reasonably good (~40-50 QPS, about 100-150ms latency), but a big downside is crazy fast old gen heap growth ultimately leading to major collections every 30-40 minutes (on a very large heap, 25GB). And at that point performance is beyond unacceptable. On the other hand I can turn off caching for bbox filters, but then my latency and QPS drops (the latency goes down from 100ms => 500ms). The NumericRangeQuery javadoc talks about the great performance you can get (sub 100 ms) but now I wonder if that was with filterCache enabled, and nobody bothered to look at the heap growth that results. I feel like this is sort of a catch-22 since neither configuration is really acceptable.

I'm open to any ideas. My last idea (untried) is to use geo hash (and pray that it either performs better with cache=false, or has more manageable heap growth if cache=true).

EDIT:

Precision step: default (8 for double I think)

System memory: 32GB (EC2 M2 2XL)

JVM: 24GB

Index size: 11 GB

EDIT2:

> A tdouble with precisionStep of 8 means that your doubles will be splitted in sequences of 8 bits. If all your latitudes and longitudes only differ by the last sequence of 8 bits, then tdouble would have the same performance has a normal double on a range query. This is why I suggested to test a precisionStep of 4.

Question: what does this actually mean for a double value?

Comment: What precisionStep are you using for your tdouble field? System-wise, is there some memory left for the OS cache? Can you share the total amount of memory of your system, the amount given to the JVM and the size of your index (in bytes)?

Comment: @jpountz: see updated question, just not sure how to get index size.

Comment: Under unix, just run `du -hs indexDir`. Under Windows, I think you can achieve this by right-click then propertis on the index directory.

Answer (score 1):

Having a profile of Solr while responding to your spatial queries would be of great help to understand what is slow, see [hprof](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/HPROF.html) for example.

Still, here are a few ideas on how you could (perhaps) improve latency.

First you could try to test what happens when decreasing the [precisionStep](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html#precisionStepDesc) (try 4 for example). If the latitudes and longitudes are too close of each other and the precisionStep is too high, Lucene cannot take advantage of having several indexed values.

You could also try to give a little bit less memory to the JVM in order to give the OS cache more chances to cache frequently accessed index files.

Then, if it is still not fast enough, you could try to extend replace TrieDoubleField as a sub field by a field type that would use [a frange query](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/search/FunctionRangeQParserPlugin.html) for the getRangeQuery method. This would reduce the number of disk access while computing the range at the cost of a higher memory usage. (I have never tested it, it might provide horrible performance as well.)

Comment: hi, can you explain what you mean about "if the latitudes and longitudes are too close of each other and the precision step is too high, Lucene cannot take advantage of having several indexed values." In my particular case I'm creating a bounding box that is anywhere from 1 mile to 20 miles (I'm guessing that 1 mile and 5 miles is most frequent, but I haven't specifically checked yet).

Comment: since my index takes 11GB on disk, should I assume it takes about the same for the OS to cache the whole thing? Does the index size on disk account for stored fields, or is it strictly indexes? I know one recommendation I've seen is to reduce stored fields down to a document key, and then manage documents outside of SOLR (i.e. only do indexing in solr).

Comment: also, can you comment on geohash? it appears to be an alternate implementation (i.e. just change schema.xml) and then point the bbox filter query to the geohash field.

Comment: A tdouble with precisionStep of 8 means that your doubles will be splitted in sequences of 8 bits. If all your latitudes and longitudes only differ by the last sequence of 8 bits, then tdouble would have the same performance has a normal double on a range query. This is why I suggested to test a precisionStep of 4.

Comment: If your index is 11G, then the OS cache can potentially cache everything, no problem here. But again, we are speculating. Having profile data would help find the bottleneck.

Comment: if I was to profile with say yourkit or jprofiler, what would I look for? How would I know if os cache does not have enough space? I understand how profiling is useful for applications that I have written, but I'm not sure how well it would work for something like SOLR (where none of the code is mine). Is it still a matter of looking for memory hogs and cpu hot spots? It seems to me to be less obvious than normal profiling...do you know of a good web article on this topic?